# What is the definition of first render in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rendering, render

I am confused when will the first render happen. I tried following to figure it out.

```
//login.js
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('first render');
    }, []);
```

I have navigation like this: login.js(console.log success)=>home.js=>login.js(console.log fail)
Is that because I have navigation history of login.js which make it not first render?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using `react-navigation`, your intuition is right.  In pure React (for the web), useEffect would run again, because the component would have been unmounted when you navigated, and mount again (as if for the first time) when you went back.

However, in `react-navigation/native`, the component stays mounted in your stack, and will not re-render on navigating back to it.  However, the "child" would be unmounted when you navigated back.  For example, if you navigated from `login => home => login => home`, `home` would be unmounted when going back to `login`.  If you had put your useEffect inside `home`, in this scenario, it would run twice.

[This is discussed in their docs here.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/)